# HACK Lambda Example -- what?

Tags: php, lambda, hhvm, hacklang

Can someone explain how this works?

http://docs.hhvm.com/manual/en/hack.lambda.php

Variables are captured automatically and transitively (including $this):

```
<?hh
$z = 11;
$foo = $x ==> $y ==> $x * $z + $y;
$bar = $foo(5);
var_dump($bar(4)); // outputs 59
```

Answer (score 9):

Conceptually, `$foo` is like a function with 2 inputs, x and y.  Calling `$foo` is like a partial function evaluation that sets x=5.  The `$bar` call then evaluates the function with y=4.  So you end up with x * z + y = 5 * 11 + 4 = 59.

To put it another way, `$foo` is a lambda that evaluates to another lambda.  So `$bar` becomes a lambda that evaluates to a number.

```
$z = 11

$foo = $x ==> $y ==> $x * $z + $y;
// foo = f(x,y,z) = x * z + y

$bar = $foo(5);                 // $bar is now $y ==> 5 * $z + $y
// bar = f(y,z) = 5 * z + y

$result = $bar(4);              // this gives you 5 * $z + 4 = 59
// result = f(z) = 5 * z + 4

var_dump(result);               // outputs 59
```

Comment: Is $foo(5) evaluated before it is assigned to $bar?

So in this line: $bar = $foo(5) what has $bar become?

Comment: @BobBrunius yes, it's evaluated -- but it evaluates to another lambda.